# Advanced postage / packaging solution

Tags: magento-1.6, delivery

I'm looking for solution that will allow me to calculate packaging cost by weight and dimensions.

User will have to pay for:

- package up to 30kg - pice I
- package fits half-pallet - price II
- package required full pallet - price III

Also:

- When someone orders 2 items that fits half-pallet, he'll have to pay price II.
- When someone orders 3 items that fits half-pallet, he'll have to pay price II + price III.
- Smaller products ( up to given weight ) can be mixed with larger ie. items that requires half-pallet, so delivery cost is set to 'price II'

**Summary**:

I'm looking for extension ( free / paid ) / advice tat will allow me to set proper delivery cost. I'm running Magento 1.6.2.

This reminds me Hanoi tower ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is a shipping extension that allows you to do that (I'd guess webshopapps would have one).

Of course you could also create your own shipping extension, if you want to learn how to do that. In a nutshell:

- Define your carrier model in your extensions config.xml:

  `default/shipping/carriers/yourcode/active` = `1`
  `default/shipping/carriers/yourcode/model` = `your_extension/carrier_name`
  Make sure `yourcode` does **NOT** contain an underscore!
- Create your shipping carrier model class, extend it from `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract` and have it implement `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Interface`
- Implement the methods `collectRates()` and `getAllowedMethods()`

In the `collectRates()` method you can do your packaging calculation. There are different ways to implement custom packaging, but this is the easiest way.

For further information check the carrier `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Flatrate`.

**One gotcha to be aware of**:
All shipping carriers inherit the method `Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Abstract::getTotalNumOfBoxes()`. This method is used to calculate and set the value of the property `$this->_numBoxes`.
So far, all good, except that the method doesn't return the number of boxes, but the average weight of the boxes! The method name and the return value do not match at all!

If you want to use the method or the property, feel free to override it in your carrier model, just return the weight and use `$this->_numBoxes` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I'll have to create own carrier - I was afraid that it'll end that way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As vinai said, web shop apps have one - product matrix allows calculation on weight, volume and destination whilst being split by type of product. i use it myself